# Why is "ls -d */"! not working in scala?

Tags: scala

```
scala> import sys.process._
import sys.process._

scala> "ls -d */".!
ls: */ : No such file or directory
res0: Int = 2
```

How can i get all folders in the current directory?

I found this solution http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-function-list-subdirectories-in-directory, but i'm, curious why is it not working?

Comment: The trailing slash in `*/` does nothing to restrict the output to directories only. (Why? Because the slash is only a separator, not part of the directory's name.) `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d` works, though each entry will begin with `./`. Shell is hard! Much better to take @tuxdna's approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "*" expansion is handled by the shell.  Try this.

```
scala> "sh -c ls -d */".!
```

**UPDATE**

This should give you the output you're looking for.  Not sure about the underlying mechanism.

```
Seq("sh", "-c", "ls -d */").!
```

Comment: Hmm there is no more error, but it shows all files it should only show the directories.

Comment: That's not what `-d` does "-d, --directory             list directories themselves, not their contents".

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in other answer, `*` is expanded by the shell and not by Java/Scala.

Seems like you are only interested in finding directories list in current directory. For that spawning a separate shell is definitely an overkill.

This can be done in Scala ( or Java ) pretty easily:

```
scala> import java.io.File
import java.io.File

scala> new File("./").listFiles()
res3: Array[java.io.File] = Array(./dir1, ./file1)

scala> new File("./").listFiles().filter(_.isDirectory)
res4: Array[java.io.File] = Array(./dir1)
```